# Why does sample attribute on a non-empty dataframe return empty dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a non empty dataframe in pySpark, called `centroids`, from which I have to sample a single row, but by using `sample` I get an empty dataframe.

I try to sample this way:

```
centroids.cache()
centroids.count()

sample_row = centroids.sample(withReplacement=False, fraction=1/centroids.count(),seed=42).limit(1)
```

but when I do `sample_row.count()` it returns 0.
I cached the centroids dataframe and triggered the action by counting, which also confirmed that the dataframe is non-empty (it has 6 rows), so what could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Try adding a small number to fraction value e.g. 0.002 or something `1.0/centroids.count() + 0.002`

Comment: Make sure you are doing float division rather than integer division. Hence 1.0 in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation of the sample function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample.html), it is stated that:

> This is not guaranteed to provide exactly the fraction specified of the total count of the given DataFrame.

Basically, with a dataframe of size `5`, and a sample ratio of `1/5`, you will get one record on average. You could obtain 0 record, 1 record or even up to 5 records. Let's illustrate this with an example:

```py
df = spark.range(5)
[df.sample(0.2).count() for i in range(10)]
# yields [1, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

As you can see, one on average, but rarely exactly one, sometimes 0.

If you want to take exactly one record at random, you could add a random column, sort by that column and take the first record like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
random_row = df.orderBy(F.rand()).head()
```

Also, if your centroids are the result of a random algorithm like `k-means`, it might be enough to just use `head()`.